# Getting The query contains references do Elements defined in the context of other data Error

Tags: c#, linq

I'm facing some problem with `DataGridView`.
I have two LINQ queries:

```
var query = from x in db.grupyTowarowes
            where x.typ == typMoneta
            select new
                   {
                      x.grupa
                   };

var test = from z in dbContext.Pick
           join g in db.grupyTowarowes on z.Group equals g.grupa
           where z.Number == 1000 && g.typ == typMoneta
           select new
                  {
                      z.Group
                  };
```

And then I am setting `DataSource`:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = test;
```

Query probably works correctly (don't have any errors with query) but I had some error with binding DataGridView, the error which i got is :

> The query contains references do Elements defined in the context of other data.

It's weird because when I set:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
```

Then the output is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using two data contexts in join (`db`,`dbContext`), But Linq does not allow join based on multiple contexts!

So you can fetch the records from one source, iterate it to join with another source;

```
var list1 = dbContext.Pick.ToList();
var list2 = db.grupyTowarowes.ToList();

var test = from z in list1
           join g in list2 on z.ID equals g.Id
           select new
           {
               z.A
           };
```

Or materialize your query by using `AsEnumerable` will fix your issue
 :

```
 var test = from z in dbContext.Pick.AsEnumerable()
            join g in db.grupyTowarowes.AsEnumerable() on z.Group equals g.grupa
            where z.Number == 1000 && g.typ == typMoneta
            select new
            {
                z.Group
            };
```

With `AsEnumerable` after data is loaded, any further operation is performed using Linq to Objects, on the data already in memory.

Comment: Now the query is execution for like 10min and nothing happend. When I run it without AsEnumerable then queries execute in 15sec and just got error with DGV

Comment: @takiTamNick With `AsEnumerable` after data is loaded, any further operation is performed using Linq to Objects, on the data already in memory. This is why it takes long time.

Comment: @takiTamNick Also you are using two data contexts in join (db,dbContext) Do you really require two data contexts??

Comment: Yes, because im using two differents Data Bases

Comment: Just saw this, 1st one doesnt gave me any result but when i check the DiagnosticTool it start taking memory - starts at 19MB and end at over 700MB(stopped by me) ! And the result still wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Use ToList()

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = test.ToList();
```

Comment: probably it's because of you are using two different data source

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your second query is, you are trying to `JOIN` from two different DB's as pointed below which is not possible. Better, you run each query separately and perform a `LINQ - Object` join to get the result

```
from z in dbContext.Pick
           join g in db.grupyTowarowes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<String>(test.ToList());
```